# Restore content file_get_content() function

Tags: php

I gave an image as a parameter to the file_get_content() function and received it as the output of a string. Now I want to do the opposite of this operation. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it back to an image file using [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.file-put-contents.php)

Example:

```
$pathToImage = '/images/test.png';
$newFile = '/images/test-new.png';


// Get the contents of the image file
$imgString = file_get_contents($pathToImage);

// Write it back to an image
file_put_contents($newFile, $imgString);
```

If you then look into your folder "images/", there should be a new file called "test-new.png"

Answer (score 0):

Deal with image using base64
with [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Online base64 image converte as string [encode image](https://base64.guru/converter/encode/image)

```
<?php

// Image as base64 truncated
$data = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAY8AAAFwCAYA...';

list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);

$image = 'image.png';

file_put_contents($image, $data);

echo "<img src='$file' alt='image' />";
```